# Source for exemption of hekdesh by nizkei adam

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, torts-damages, bava-kamma, hekdesh

What is the source of the פטור (exemption) of הקדש by נזקי אדם (damage to property done by a person)?

Tosfos on Bava Kama [7a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=21&daf=7&format=pdf) (continued from [6b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=21&daf=6b&format=pdf) sv שור רעהו; on 7a, beginning of narrow lines) teaches that the פטור of all מזיקים when they damage הקדש is from a מה הצד between אדם, קרן, and שור פסולי המוקדשים by בור. Now I know that קרן is פטור from "שור רעהו ולא שור של הקדש" (bottom of [6b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=21&daf=6b&format=pdf)) and שור פסולי המוקדשים comes from "והמת יהיה לו" (later on, [10a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=21&daf=10&format=pdf) (before the 2 dots)); **but where does נזקי אדם come from?**

---

*Note: This question is not a question according to Rashi, because he holds that all מזיקים are פטורים by הקדש because of the פסוק of רעהו -- Rashi on [9b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=21&daf=9b&format=pdf) sv נכסים שאין בהם מעילה.*

Comment: Is it so obvious that Rashi holds that there's no nizkei adam for hekdesh? His second explanation sounds very much like there would be, with the exception of karka

Comment: @Matt Which "second explanation" are you referring to?

Comment: Rashi gives two explanations for the petur of hekdesh on the bottom of 6b. Sorry if I'm wrong, this is from memory and I can't look it up now

Comment: @Matt Even according to the Maharshal's reading of that Rashi, I think the *lishna basra* is just saying that *shein* and *regel* would be liable, not אדם. A brief discussion of the Maharam's reading vs. the Maharshal's reading can be found on the [KBY website](http://www.kby.org.il/hebrew/torat-yavneh/view.asp?id=4772).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Tosafos* ([*Bava M'tzi'a'* 99b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=22&daf=99b&format=text), s.v. פרט למזיק) indicate that the exegetical basis for the teaching found in the mishna ([*Bava Kama* 9b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=21&daf=9b&format=text), נכסים שאין בהן מעילה) and the *Y'rushalmi* ([*Gitin* 5:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r3505.htm), דתני רבי חייה נזקין להדיוט ואין נזקין לגבוה) that אדם is not liable for damages to הקדש is found in *Chagiga* ([10b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=13&daf=10b&format=text), מעילה דילפא חטא חטא מתרומה), where a גזרה שווה is made between a verse about מעילה in *Vayikra* ([5:13](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0305.htm#13), נֶפֶשׁ כִּי תִמְעֹל מַעַל **וְחָטְאָה** בִּשְׁגָגָה) and a verse about תרומה in *B'midbar* ([18:32](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0418.htm#32), וְלֹא תִשְׂאוּ עָלָיו **חֵטְא** בַּהֲרִימְכֶם אֶת חֶלְבּוֹ מִמֶּנּוּ; see also Rashi to *Chagiga* ad loc., s.v. מעילה ילפינן).

*Tosafos* indicate that just as a person is only liable for benefiting from *t'ruma* (per [*Vayikra* 22:14](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0322.htm#14)), so to is a person not liable for merely damaging *hekdesh*.